# useMemo not running when "data" from Apollo useQuery hook returns a new value for "data" on which useMemo is dependent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client, react-usememo

I have a component that uses useQuery Apollo Hook to fetch data from a GraphQL API. This component also has a useMemo that has the data variable returned from the useQuery Apollo hook as a dependency.
The useMemo runs initially on the first render of the component as it should. Then it runs again when data from useQuery comes back. I follow this up by making some changes to the data variable inside useQuery.

Now when I re-render this component in another tab, the useQuery runs once on initial render, as it should, but doesn't run again when the data from useQuery comes back.
Note: that I modified that data variable inside useMemo in the previous tab and graphql api returned a new data value, so useMemo should be able to spot that, but somehow it does not.

Possible reasons upon my investigation:

1. useMemo would only run the second time in the second tab if the "data" variable was on the state of the function and does not run when new data from useQuery comes back and useQuery re-renders the component since it does not have visibility to the change.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
functional component: {
  const { data, loading, error: loadRolesError } = useQuery();

  const result = useMemo(()=>{
    // changing data inside here
  }, [data])
}
```

Comment: what? use effect, not memo ... separate tabs = separate states/instances ... you can't change loaded data, apollo returns read only data ... prepare more real and editable [example] and more detailed description ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back - I figured out the problem, the reason of the bug was as follows - The problem happening in my component was that I was changing the "data" value returned from the useQuery hook directly within my component logic. useMemo was't running because of changing "data" which is a state variable directly outside the knowledge of React. And I also confirmed that useQuery is re-rendering my component successfully on data change.

Comment: And separate tabs were sharing the same state since data is an object and they're copied by reference. I was modifying it directly without using useEffect. So it was being shared.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Apollo's [useReactiveVar](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/%5D) hook tor this use case. From the docs
`With the useReactiveVar hook, React components can also include reactive variable values in their state directly, without wrapping them in a query.`

there are a few parts to this so I have sketched out a solution below that gives all the pieces with imports declarations and possible implementations starting with dependencies

```
import React, { useEffect, useState,  useMemo } from 'react';
import { useReactiveVar, makeVar, useLazyQuery, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
```

make the apollo cache  variables

```js
   export const dataWillUpdate = {
      // some nice flat schema data object,
      niceFlatSchemaData: {}
      };
   const dataWillUpdateVar = makeVar(dataWillUpdate);
```

```js
const component = () => {
    // make the reactive apollo variable
    const dataWillUpdateVarReactive = useReactiveVar(dataWillUpdateVar);
    // memo the niceFlatSchemaData data object
    const niceFlatSchemaData = useMemo(() => userProfileVarReactive.niceFlatSchemaData, [
        dataWillUpdateVarReactive.niceFlatSchemaData,
    ]);
    // see 2 for lazy queries
    const [ getData, { data, loading, error: loadRolesError} ] = useLazyQuery();  


    useEffect(() => {
        // will update here when change to niceFlatSchemaData
        // so run query here
        getData({variables:{input:{
            // nice flat input object for the gql
        }}})
    }, [niceFlatSchemaData])

    useEffect(() => {
        // will update here when quer calls back
        // state changes for render
     
    }, [data])

}
```

need to have the variables configured in the apollo cache

```js
const globalCache = new InMemoryCache({

    typePolicies: {
        Query: {
            fields: {
                dataWillUpdate: {
                    read() {
                        return dataWillUpdateVar();
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

[1]  [useReactiveVar](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/%5D)
[2] [lazy query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. The problem happening in my component was that I was changing the "data" value returned from the useQuery hook directly within my component logic. useMemo was't running because of changing "data" which is a state variable directly outside the knowledge of React. And I also confirmed that useQuery is re-rendering my component succesfully on data change.